# "10-cm square" is OK?

Tags: expressions, mathematics

I'd like to say that we need to draw a square of which each edge length is 10 cm (i.e., 100 square cm).

What is the simplest way to represent such shape? Is the following sentence makes sense?

> We need to draw a 10-cm rectangle.
>
> We need to draw a rectangle each side 10 cm.

I think this is a very boring and childish question. However, this kind of simple thing is sometimes difficult for non-native English speakers. Please help.

Comment: I would use *a 10-(cm-)by-10-cm square*. I'm not sure if *a 10-cm square* really works. Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, all squares are rectangles, but we probably wouldn't call it a "rectangle" if it were actually a square.

So, instead of saying:

> We need to draw a rectangle...

we would say:

> We need to draw a square...

Now there's the part about how to best describe the square – which is anything but childish! There are a few ways to do this:

> We need to draw a square with 10 cm sides.
>   We need to draw a square where each side is ten centimeters long.

If we want more brevity, though, we can also use *10 cm* as an adjectival phrase modifying the word *square*:

> We need to draw a 10 cm square.

That's the technique used on [this web page](http://www3.rmsc.org/museum/kidsclub/experiments/kaleidoscope/kaleidoscope_making.htm):

> Cut a 10 cm square piece of wax paper and a 10cm square piece of plastic wrap.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Both longer and brevity expressions are helpful for my purpose. How great community here is...

Answer (score 3):

J.R.'s answer is excellent.  There is one *very* brief way to refer to a square he didn't mention:

***# "by" #*** can be used if the units are obvious or unimportant.  For instance:

> The teacher gave each of his students a ruler and told them to draw a **four by four** square on a piece of writing paper.

Here we may not know if the square is meant to be 4"x4" or 4cm x 4cm.  Most Americans would assume the former, the rest of the world would assume the latter.

Context could inform that, though.

> First the teacher had his student draw a circle with a 3 inch radius.  Then he asked them to draw a **two by two square** inside the circle, and a **seven by ten rectangle** around the circle.

Comment: You could use this and also include the units: *"Draw a 10 cm by 10 cm square."* But in that case the *"# by #"* is an adjective, so you should end with *"square"* or *"rectangle"*.

Comment: Of related interest, it's also the norm in construction and other trades to say of a 10-ft by 10-foot space, "this room is ten feet square"; or of a 100'x100' plot of land, "this plot is 100 feet square". Accordingly, it's rare and confusing to say "feet squared" in place of "square feet", even if it's being written as ft².